# Listen for orientation change when screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am wanting to listen for an orientation change in an activity.  I've attempted some of the usual things,

- `onConfigurationChange` with orientation in the `android:configChanges` element
  in the manifest,
- There's no restart of the activity, (proved with breakpoints), so I can't check `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()` after a rotation unless I check it constantly in my draw thread, which is wasteful.
- I could use `OrientationEventListener` but this gets called for every degree change of the phone, which (imo) is also wasteful.

I am trying to detect the difference from LandscapeLeft and LandscapeRight.  I'm unsure how else to approach it at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the `OrientationEventListener` will necessarily tell you whether or not the screen's orientation has changed since it only returns the degrees.

Using `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()` is probably the way to go, but you would have to know the device's default orientation since this will only tell you the rotation based on the default.

There's a decent blog about using the various sensors with orientation changes and the coordinate system [here.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html)